# Tangent lines to a circle

Tags: geometry, line

If I have a point B tangent to a circle with known radius r, and a point D outside the circle, how do I find the intersection of tangent lines through B and D?

If the only known values are the blue ones as shown in the sketch, how do I find point E?
I guess I'm missing the math background to combine similar examples with other known values to come to a solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By running some more synthetic geometry first, you can apply the law of cosines on triangle BCD to express CD, then use in Pythagoras' theorem for triangle CDF to find the length d of of DF. Then, apply the law of cosines to the triangle BDE to find the length e of EF, where e = DE - d. Since EB = EF = e you just have to make the vector AB unit first and then multiply by e to find vector BE. After that just add the coordinates of B to BE.

The point H is the other point on the line AB such that the line DH is the other tangent to the circle.

```py
import numpy as np
import math
'''
input A, B, D, r
'''
A = [ 0,-4] 
B = [-1, 1]
D = [ 5, 0]
r = 2


A = [  5.49, -8.12] 
B = [  1.24,  1.82]
D = [ 15.95, -1.12] 
r = 3

A = np.array(A)
B = np.array(B)
D = np.array(D)

AB = B - A
l_AB = math.sqrt(AB[0]**2 + AB[1]**2)
AB = AB / l_AB

BD = D - B
l_BD = math.sqrt(BD[0]**2 + BD[1]**2)

cos_alpha = (-AB[0]*BD[0] - AB[1]*BD[1]) / l_BD
sin_alpha = math.sqrt(1 - cos_alpha**2)

d = math.sqrt( l_BD**2 - 2*r*l_BD*sin_alpha )

e = (l_BD**2 - d**2) / (2*d - 2*l_BD*cos_alpha)
E = B + e*AB

h = (l_BD**2 - d**2) / (2*d + 2*l_BD*cos_alpha)
H = B - h*AB

AB_perp = [AB[1], -AB[0]]
AB_perp = np.array(AB_perp)
C = B + r*AB_perp

CE = E - C
l2_CE = CE[0]**2 + CE[1]**2
G = C + (r**2 / l2_CE)*CE

F = B + 2*(G - B)

print('E =', E)
print('H =', H)
print('C =', C)
print('G =', G)
print('F =', F)
```

Comment: Thank you for your neat solution! It works great for finding E with very few calculations. I got some weird results on G, maybe I did something wrong while translating the code. I'll study better the geometry you are describing and I'll try to fix it. Thank you so much!

Comment: @AlexK what input data are you feeding the algorithm? What is weird about the result for point G? My test-example shows that E and G are the right points. Can you post the coordinates of the points you are applying the algorithm on? Also, upvote and/or approve answers that you find helpful and relevant to your question.

Comment: I used these values:  A = { 5.49,-8.12} 
B = {1.24, 1.82}
D = { 15.95, -1.12}
r = 3. Result is correct for E = {-2.6051, 10.8131}. For G the output is {1.9425, 0.1769} while the correct position is {3.43, 3.67}. I already tried to upvote but is says I need reputation of at least 15 to be able to upvote. It's my first post.

Comment: @AlexK why do you think that {3.43, 3.67} is the correct position for point G? It is not. The correct position is the calculated one {1.9425, 0.1769}. The two points E and G must lie on the line AB and have to be the vertices of the triangle DEG for which the circle of radius r=3 and tangent to AB at B is the incircle. The position  {3.43, 3.67} is not even on the line AB.

Comment: @AlexK Ah, I see, my notations are off. I denote by G something different from your G. I changed the notation to H.

Comment: Ok sorry. I was confused because I name G the midpoint of the chord on the sketch. I just saw that this point is the intersection of the other tangent line. My bad..

Comment: @AlexK I added extra lines of code to calculate the positions of all the points C, G, E, F and H. However, there are ways to calculate some of them without calculating some of the other points. I used whatever is available and convenient.

Answer (score 1):

We can write two vector equations:

-vector **EB** is perpendicular to radius **CB**, so dot product is zero

```
EB.dot.CB = 0  or
(ex - bx)*(bx - cx) + (ey - by)*(by - cy) = 0   (1)
```

-squared distance from center **C** to line **DE** is equal to squared radius (using vector product)

```
(DC x ED)^2 / |ED|^2 = R^2
((dx-cx)*(ey-dy)-(dy-cy)*(ex-dx))^2 = R^2 * ((ex-dx)^2+(ey-dy)^2)     (2)
```

Equations `(1)` and `(2)` form equation system for two unknowns `ex, ey`. Solve it, get 0, 1 or 2 solutions (due to quadratic equation)

Comment: Thank you! Now I'm getting somewhere. If we don't know the position of the center of the circle is it right to say, slopeAB = -1/slopeBC and Bx^2+By^2=r^2 and find Cx, Cy?     
[1]   (By-Ay)/(Bx-Ax) = - 1 / ((Cy-By)/(Cx-Bx))
[2]    Bx^2 + By^2 = r^2

Comment: correct equation `(Cx-Bx)^2+(Cy-By)^2=r^2`. (but in my opinion, vector approach is better)

Comment: After solving the equation system on matlab and finding some equations that are 108372 characters long, I can say that if you choose the correct roots the results are accurate! Thank you!

Comment: Yes, math packets might provide enormously gigantic formulas, when they don't simplify :( By hands - make formula for ey from the first equation, substitute into the second, sepatate coeeficients for ex powes -  so we'll have quadratic equation for ex.